# Get the message from Azure Service Bus whenever needed

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

Is it possible to retrieve message whenever needed in my application?

All I need is to not declare any handle who accept messages when there is a message in Queue (this I can implement using QueueClient) because I want to process one message at a time. Once successfully processed single message then only I need another message from Queue.

Is this possible with Service Bus?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some code? I guess you can make use of Azure triggers. You can read about them here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---configuration

Comment: @Shahid my problem is my queue is session queue,So I could not use Function as it does not support as of now to handle session based message. I am fetching message using "client.RegisterSessionHandler" handler, and it gives all the messages available in queue.

Answer (score 1):

Service bus has this property of "Message Deferral", Would you be OK to defer message till you complete processing current one ?

Message deferral
When a queue or subscription client receives a message that it is willing to process, but for which processing is not currently possible due to special circumstances within the application, the entity has the option to [defer retrieval of the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral) to a later point. The message remains in the queue or subscription, but it is set aside.

Answer (score 0):

[RegisterSessionHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.registersessionhandler?view=azure-dotnet) has a property  [MessageWaitTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.sessionhandleroptions.messagewaittimeout?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_SessionHandlerOptions_MessageWaitTimeout) which allows you to wait to receive a message.

In your case if are sure about the time to process a message, then you can specify this property which will give you enough time process it. Next message will only received after the specified time.

Using this you can delay the retrieval of next message using RegisterSessionHandler.

Comment: According to the documentation "Indicates the maximum time the Session Pump should wait for receiving messages for sessions. If no message is received within the specified time, the pump will close that session and try to get messages
from a different session".In my case, there are multiple thread and single sessionId. So, continuously get the message on a handler. Hence, this property is not useful.